# c# enforcing specific method signature in derived classes (abstract virtual static)

Tags: c#, oop, static, virtual, abstract

I have an `abstract class BaseClass` and want to enforce that all `class Derived: BaseClass` have to override a method `foo` resulting in a very specific signature. The Problem is as following:

1. Classes which inherit from BaseClass **have to implement** `foo` on their own (pref. only if they are not abstract) [like `abstract`]
2. BaseClass must have a **base-implementation**, derived classes can call [like `virtual`]
3. [**Signature** of `foo` in derived classes should be `static` (the classes themself are not!) [eddit: omitted]]
4. **Arguments** of `foo` are of `class Derived`/`this.GetType()` (pref. without changing signature of BaseClass)

It is already hard enough/ impossible(?) to combine two of these (exept 4.), but maybe there are some clever workarounds and I take what I can get. At last here is some pseudo code to better reflect my intention:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    bool baseBool;
    public abstract virtual static bool foo(BaseClass b1, BaseClass b2)
    {
        //sample code
        return b1.baseBool ^ b2.baseBool;
    }
}

public class Derived: BaseClass
{
    bool derivedBool;
    public static override bool foo(Derived d1, Derived d2)
    {
        //sample code
        return base.foo(d1, d2) && d1.derivedBool ^ d2.derivedBool;
    }
}
```

### Solution based on accepted answer by lidqy

```cs
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    bool baseBool;
    public abstract bool foo(BaseClass b1, BaseClass b2);
}

public abstract class BaseClassWrappedCRTP<T>: BaseClass where T: BaseClassWrappedCRTP<T>
{
    public override bool foo(BaseClass b1, BaseClass b2)
    {
        //sample code
        return b1.baseBool ^ b2.baseBool && fooWrappedCRTP((T)b1, (T)b2);
    }

    protected abstract bool fooWrappedCRTP(T d1, T d2);
}

public class Derived: BaseClassWrappedCRTP<Derived>
{
    bool derivedBool;
    protected override bool fooWrappedCRTP(Derived d1, Derived d2)
    {
        //sample code
        return d1.derivedBool ^ d2.derivedBool;
    }
}
```

Note that if Derived were `abstract class Derived: BaseClassWrappedCRTP<Derived>`, we would need `abstract class DerivedWrappedCRTP<T>: Derived where T: DerivedWrappedCRTP<T>` to continue inheritance of `foo` in this way (Given an actual need to access non-generic `Derived`).

Comment: The concept of `static override` makes no sense. You might be looking for a Roslyn Analyser: that will let you raise compile-time errors if people don't follow your rules

Comment: You can't override static methods, so 1, 2, 3 together are impossible. If you exclude 3, I think it can be done. 1 is just `abstract`, 2 can be done with a protected concrete method in the base class, and 4 can be done with the curiously recurring template pattern. If you really want 3, you should [edit] your question to give more context as to *why* you need it, so that we can come up with a workaround.

Comment: @Sweeper I guess I could ommit 3, it just felt to be the right thing to do, since `foo` doesn't use references of `this`.
Regarding CRTP (thanks for the name): I have to be able to access `foo` from a `List<BaseClass<T>>` with mixed `T`. List declaration/ instantiation would be possible with a wrapper class/ Interface but that would hide the existance of `foo`?

Comment: Hold on, wasn't `foo` meant to be static in the first place? Why do you need to access `foo` from a `List<BaseClass<T>>`? You wouldn't be able to do that even if `foo` were static.

Comment: Assuming that `foo` is non-static and you _somehow_ achieved 4, how would accessing `foo` from `List<BaseClass>` with mixed subclasses work _at all_? You don't know which specific subclass each list element is! Let's say you do `theList[0].foo(new Subclass1(), new Sublcass1())`, but actually, `theList[1]` contains instances of `Subclass2`. According to 4, they are supposed to accept instances of `Subclass2`, but you gave it `Subclass1`. The compiler has no way of checking whether you are calling `foo` correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments inheritance and staticness don't fit.
From what you told I think this code might match your use case...

```
//declare the mixed lists with List<IBase> to get rid of the type params
interface IBase {
   bool foo(BaseClass b1, BaseClass b2);
} 

public abstract class BaseClass<T> : IBase where T : BaseClass
{
    bool baseBool;
    //If you call Foo from a "mixed list" use non generic, base class parameters, else you get casting troubles enumerating and calling 'foo'
    public bool foo(BaseClass b1, BaseClass b2)
    {
        //sample code
        return b1.baseBool ^ b2.baseBool && fooOverride((T)b1, (T)b2);
    }
    protected abstract bool fooOverride(T b1, T b2);

}

public class Derived : BaseClass<Derived>
{
    bool derivedBool;
    protected override bool fooOverride(Derived d1, Derived d2)
    {
        //sample code
        return d1.derivedBool ^ d2.derivedBool;
    }
}
```